# Easy way to do 'login' in WCF & Silverlight

Tags: .net, silverlight, wcf, security

I wrote a Silverlight client - and in some place in the code I need to do 'login' ==> the user needs to input their username & password and this information will send to WCF server that will return 'true' if the user name is in the Database and the password is correct.

My Question:

Is there some easy way or some class in WCF and in Silverlight that can make this easier?

I know that I just can send the class DTO that will contain user name and password (2 strings) and the server will just return true/false - but I want to have a more secure way and use something that exists already in WCF/Silverlight.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the proper security mode, for example, message security mode. Then, you can specify UserName as the client credential, this requires you send the username and password to the server when you are trying to connect the server. And this information will be encrypted so that nobody except the server can know the username and password.

Of course, you can also customize the validation logic by developing a class inheriting from UserNamePasswordValidator, which you can put your validation logic here.

It's a little complicated to prvoide a sample for you, I'm sorry, but I found a link that may help you:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702565.aspx